# Elastic Search Standard Analyzer + Synonyms

Tags: elasticsearch

I am attempting the get Synonyms added to our current way of searching for products.

The mappings ( part of ) looks like this currently :

```js
{
  "keywords": {
    "properties": {
      "modifiers": {
        "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "standard"
      },
        "nouns": {
          "type": "string",
            "analyzer": "standard"
        }
    }
  }
}
```

I am interested in use the `synonyms filter` along with the `standard analyzer`. And as per the [document here from elastic search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/analysis.html) the right way to do that is to add

```js
{
    'analysis': {
      'analyzer': {
        "synonym" : {
          "tokenizer" : 'standard',
          "filter" : ['standard', 'lowercase', 'stop', 'external_synonym']
        }
      },
      'filter': {
        'external_synonym': {
          'type': 'synonym',
          'synonyms': synonyms
        }
      }
    }
```

into the mappings and use that in the `analyzer` field in the snippet above. **But** this does not work - in the sense that - the behaviour is quite different ( even without adding any synonyms ).

I am interested in preserving the relevancy behaviour ( as provided by the `standard analyzer` ) and just added the synonyms list.

Could someone please provide more information on how to **exactly** replicate the `standard analyzer` behaviour ?

Comment: could you given an example of how  is it different with/without synonyms ?

Comment: also make sure to configure your `stop` token filter with `_none_` to match standard analyzer the default is `_english_` `https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-stop-tokenfilter.html`

Comment: @keety I have tried with stop token filter as none and still it does show the same kind of results. 

Also to note is that, the synonyms are not even part of the picture here. I just want to be able to replace the standard analyzer with a custom analyzer but same have same behaviour as standard ( so that I can tag on synonyms filter to it).

Comment: is it feasible to post an example demonstrating this difference  ? Probably  [Analyze](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.2/indices-analyze.html) API should help  illustrate the difference .